# Hyperledger Composer: Generating a QUERY using FROM

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm currently developing an Application that uses hyperledger composer.
I use the standard Composer Query Language for queries.

Since I've never seen any query using 'FROM' statement and cannot find any of them online, I wanted to know if any of you already wrote one.

In specific, I have two assets:

```
asset First identified by name{
  o String name
}

asset Second identified by name{
 o String name
 -->First[] firsts
}
```

and want to create a query that given an asset 'SECOND' (or it's ID), returns every 'FIRST' contained.

I thought that something like this might work, but actually it doesn't.

```
query selectFirstsGivenSeconds{
 description: "some description"
 statement: 
   SELECT namespace.First
   FROM namespace.Second.firsts
   WHERE (name == _$secondName)
}
```

Does anyone ever wrote a Query with 'FROM' keyword in this query language?